# Is there any way to add another PictureURL property in User Profile?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-userprofile

I need to add a PictureURL property in User Profile service. This property will have users signature associated with it. So when user sign any document, approval workflow gets the users sign and add it in signature block.

This column will be visible to user in user profile and user can changes it in user profile. Is there any way we can create second PictureURL property in User Profile?

Update:
I have not find a way to do it. but for my issue I have created a URL field which stores value of user sign image.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Create a user profile property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262327.aspx)

> **1.** Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a member of the Farm Administrators SharePoint group or is a Service
>   Application Administrator for the User Profile service application.
>
> **2.** On Central Administration, in the Application Management section, click Manage service applications.
>
> **3.** On the Manage Service Applications page, in the Type column, click the User Profile service application.
>
> **4.** In the Operations group of the ribbon, click Manage.
>
> **5.** On the Manage Profile Service page, in the People section, click Manage User Properties.
>
> **6.** On the Manage User Profile Properties page, click New Property.
>
> **7.** On the Add User Profile Property page, in the Property Settings section, in the Name text box, type a name to be used by the User
>   Profile service application for the user profile property.
>
> **8.** In the Property Settings section, in the Display Name box, type the user profile property name that will be displayed to all users.
>
> **9.** On the Type drop-down list, click the data type for the property.
>   In the Length box, type the maximum number of characters that are allowed for values for this property.
>
> **10.** In the Length box, type the maximum number of characters that are allowed for values for this property.
>
> **11.** Click to select Configure a Term Set to be used for this property to associate the profile property with a managed metadata term set and
>   select a term set from the drop-down list.
>
> **12.** In the Sub-type of Profile section, select the Default User Profile Subtype to associate the default user profile subtype with
>   this user profile property.
>
> **13.** In the User Description section, in the Description box, type the instructions or information that is displayed to users about this user
>   profile property.
>
> **14.** In the Policy Settings section, select the policy setting and default privacy setting that you want for this property. Click to
>   select User can override box to enable users to override these
>   settings.
>
> **15.** In the Edit Settings section, select whether users can edit values for this property.
>
> **16.** In the Display Settings section, specify if and how the property will be viewed by users.
>
> **17.** In the Search Settings section, select the Alias check box, the Indexed check box, or both, depending on the kinds of searches that
>   you want to be associated with this user profile property.
>
> **18.** In the Property Mapping for Synchronization section, click Remove to delete or change an existing mapping.
>
> **19.** In the Add new Mapping section, specify the source data connection, attribute, and synchronization direction for the mapping.
>   When you are finished, click Add.
>
> **20.** Click OK.

Comment: This is simple process to add new property mapping in the User Profile service. But the issue is at step 9. I have tried every type to make sure I get same profile picture column but I am not able to generate a new one.